# file transfer with ssh pipe; without scp

Tags: ssh, scp, file-transfer, pipe

**Scenario:** I'm having about hundred odd text files which are compressed as .gz. They need to be transferred to a remote server. I do not want to use scp. Both, linux servers.

**my requirement/my idea:** I want to write and execute a bash script on source server for this. What I want is like zcat each of the files, pipe that output over ssh user@remote(its already configured passwordless), then have those outputs redirected into a text file on the remote server. Is this way correct? If so how to implement this?

Thanks,

Comment: `I do not want to use scp` - why not?

Comment: @symcbean, just searching for alternatives :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
for file in $(ls dir/); do zcat ${file} | ssh user@remote "cat > /path/${file}"; done
```

Comment: great. It works but the multiple files zcatted on source server and being output to a single file on remote server because each file on source server is on average 500M and the output file on remote server is growing >2G. why would that be?

Comment: because of this "ssh user@remote "cat > /path/${file}", the source is .gz and on the remote host it's "cat" (not compressed).

Comment: Yeah, I think I would just hack it with some `tr -d` and adding the `.gz` extension on the source files.

Comment: @pkhamre, please disregard my previous comment. Your original script works just fine redirecting to multiple files, not single file. Each gz file itself was about 3G when uncompressed, which I found out later. Thanks.

Comment: just add      ssh user@remote "cat | gzip > /path/${file}"